# PHP sub url rewriting

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how can i rewrite sub URL in php
this:

```
localhost\edev\pages\UI.php?employee=1
```

into this:

```
localhost\edev\pages\UI.aspx?employee=1
```

note:
i have tried adding this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ]*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# NOTE! FOR APACHE ON WINDOWS: Add [NC] to RewriteCond like this:
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" [NC]
```

i already tried some other answers, but not works for me.
Thank You.

Comment: Show what you tried and explain what the undesired result was

Comment: Please show what you've tried, it's good that you tried before asking, but if you post what you've tried it saves times with people coming up with solutions that you haven't already tried.

Comment: @PatrickQ i've edited

Comment: Okay, and where's the part in there where you're trying to change a .php extension to a .aspx extension?

Comment: i want to change /pages/UI.php?blabla into pages/UI.aspx?blabla @PatrickQ

Comment: @PatrickQ answer?

Comment: @MohsinRaza You never answered my question.  Where is the part in your attempt that tries to changed `.php` to `.aspx`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

code:

```
$newUrl = str_replace('php', 'aspx', 'localhost\edev\pages\UI.php?employee=1');

header('Location: ' . $newUrl);
```

Comment: is this for url rewriting?